# how to check heartbeat of other server using node js

Tags: node.js, heartbeat

I implemented load balancer in node.js and want to check the availability of  my server by healthchecking on regular interval.

Can anyone please suggest any middleware that I can use for node.js or any custom implementation that can be used out for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Node.js has HTTP client functionality. You could just use Node to regularly check if your website is up. Would that be what you need?

Comment: Actually I implemented laod balancer in node.js and I have to check periodically whether servers are up or not.If anyone is down then I have to remove it from the list which I am using for the round robin implementation.It should check it continuously.
@cgf can you suggest something on this?

Comment: @cgf yes I used http.get to implement heartbeat check.Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: sorry, didn't see your second comment there. Glad I could help. You could copy/paste your solution as a comment (as much as possible) and accept is as the correct answer so that others can learn something from it as well.